# Recursive depth first search Integer ArrayList Java

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, set, depth-first-search

What I'm trying to do is essentially look at a set of numbers, and find all subsets of those numbers and eventually print them out. I'm completely stuck on writing the recursion method. The idea is to use a Boolean arraylist as a form of a tree, and traverse through it testing all the different sums for what I'm looking for. The problem is that it's not even going through the tree correctly, so any suggestions would be of great help.

```
package programmingassignment3;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class SubsetSum {

    public ArrayList<Integer> set1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
    int d = 6;

    public void  test(){
        Collections.sort(set1);
        for(int i =0;i<set1.size();i++)
            if(set1.get(i)>d)
                set1.remove(i);
        ArrayList<Boolean> set1test = new ArrayList();
        recSubSetSum(set1test); 
    }


    public void recSubSetSum(ArrayList<Boolean> subsetList)
    {

        if(sumOfList(subsetList)>=d)
            System.out.println("Output Set(WIP)");
        ArrayList<Boolean> leftList = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Boolean> rightList = new ArrayList();
        for(int i =0;i<set1.size();i++)
        {
            leftList = new ArrayList(subsetList);
            rightList = new ArrayList(subsetList);
            if(set1.size()>leftList.size())
                leftList.add(true);
            if(set1.size()>rightList.size())
                rightList.add(false);

            if(sumOfList(leftList)<d)
            {
                recSubSetSum(leftList);
                if(set1.size()>rightList.size())
                    rightList.add(false);
            }
            if(sumOfList(rightList)<d)
                recSubSetSum(rightList);
        }
    }

    public int sumOfList(ArrayList<Boolean> subSetList)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i<subSetList.size();i++)
        {

            if(subSetList.get(i))
                sum+=set1.get(i);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "not going through the tree correctly" mean exactly? What is the behavior you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question clearly.  It could help if you gave an example expected input and output.

Comment: Okay, so ideally what I want it to do is shown in this: [link]http://s29.postimg.org/p20levr1j/DFSTREE.jpg    --- As far as what It's actually doing, well, it's going beyond the bounds of the tree in many cases, and just not going through the tree as intended staying at certain points of the tree etc.

Comment: Okay, i'll give an example. So if I input 1,2,3,4 into an array list and I decided I wanted the sum to be 6 like in the current code the output would be all subsets that equate to six. for example, {1,2,3}, {4,2} .

Comment: I have not done the code to print out the outputs, but that's not what I'm worried about. It's that I'm not testing all the possible subsets correctly because it's going through the Boolean ArrayList strangely. So mainly my recSubSetSum method is screwed up somehow.

Comment: First of all, this is homework, right? Because the answer should more guide you than give you the working code. :)

Comment: @Critical, you can edit your question and add expected input and output.

Comment: I would love any type of guidance.

Comment: So do you want to return the subsets that sum up to the number, or a way to traverse this boolean tree? I'm kinda lost. :P

Comment: traversing the boolean tree for sure. Just thought explaining the purpose of the program would help explain.